# iOS sensor fusion is laggy and inaccurate, can I fix that?

Tags: iphone, ios10, sensor-fusion

I'm playing around with an app that overlays an image on top of an AV view, a sort-of-but-not-really AR app. You use it by holding the camera up in front of you like you're taking a picture of friends in front of you. Currently, it just displays a compass rose on a SceneKit object.

It *basically* works, but on my 5S and 6 and I'm finding it is:

1. laggy on startup, with the pointing vector being off by as much as 180 degrees
2. not terribly accurate, with errors even after its been running of something like 10 degrees
3. the error in (2) changes, so it's idea of "south" moves around over time

Ultimately I'm going to need the accuracy to be on the order of 5 degrees. Can anyone comment on whether this sort of accuracy is possible, if there's a way to test it, and perhaps comment on platform issues - is it better on the 7 for instance?